# Need help doing overload

Tags: c#

I'm getting a error of this: Error Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace Assignment11
{
  class Dog
  {
    public void bark()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Empty method");
    }
    public void bark(string args);

    Console.WriteLine("fido is Barking");
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Dog fido = new Dog();
      fido.bark();
      fido.bark ("fido");
      Console.Write("Hit any key to close"); Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting a error of this: Error Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration) Thanks for your help.

Comment: C# doesn't work that way. You can't decorate your "fido" instance with new methods. (That syntax exists in C#, but only for explicit interface implementations, which is a completely different scenario). If you want to overload the bark() method, you have to do it in the Dog class, or a subclass.

Answer (score 2):

The error says for itself. The `Dog` class has a method called bark which does not take any parameter.

You cannot call `fido.bark("Fido");`, you do not have a `bark(string)` method.

You could have something like this, take a look at sample with comments.

```
class Dog
{
    // signature without arguments
    public void bark()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Empty method");
    }

    // other signature for the method, which takes a string argument
    public void bark(string arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bark {0}", arg);
    }
}
```

Comment: I got this error when try doing Error'System.Console.WriteLine(string, params object[])' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type' C

Comment: @Jen990077 Assuming you typed it as you did in the edited OP, your second `bark` method ends with a semicolon instead of enclosing the `Console.WriteLine` call in brackets.

Comment: It is still showing the same error when I tried it that way too

Answer (score 0):

`public void bark(string bark)`

should be in the dog class, since you are calling bark on a dog object (fido), not a program object

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the second bark method to a different name

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Assignment11
{ 
    class Dog
    {
       public void bark()
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Empty method");
       }

       public void bark2(string args);

           Console.WriteLine("fido is Barking");
       }

  class Program
 {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          Dog fido = new Dog();
          fido.bark();
          fido.bark2 ("fido");
          Console.Write("Hit any key to close"); 
          Console.ReadKey(true);
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is still showing the same error when I tried it that way